# В чем причина рокировки строковых значений?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Приветствую. Есть корзина с товарами, изначальное положение надписи в корзине ка на рисунке [image: рис1]
Раньше такого не замечал, но сейчас при добавлении любого товара происходит вдруг рокировка цифры с надписью руб[image: рис2]
при удалении товара и перезагрузке страницы снова все встает на свои места
[image: рис3]
Что вдруг получилось?

```js
//либо этот обработчик файл woocommerce-mod.js
$('body').on(base.eventtype, '.add_to_cart_button', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    product = {},
    productContainer = $this.parents('.product').eq(0);
  product.name = productContainer.find('h3 a').text();
  product.image = productContainer.find('.thumbnail-container img');
  product.price = productContainer.find('.price .amount').last().text();

  $this.block({
    message: null,
    overlayCSS: {
      background: '#fff url(' + woocommerce_params.ajax_loader_url + ') no-repeat center',
      backgroundSize: '16px 16px',
      opacity: 0.6
    }
  });

  if (product.image.length) {
    product.image = "<img class='added-product-image' src='" + product.image.get(0).src + "' />";
  }
  base.clicked_product = product;
});

$('body').on(base.eventtype, '.add_to_cart_button', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    product = {},
    productContainer = $this.parents('.product').eq(0);
  product.name = productContainer.find('h3 a').text();
  product.image = productContainer.find('.thumbnail-container img');
  product.price = productContainer.find('.price .amount').last().text();

  $this.block({
    message: null,
    overlayCSS: {
      background: '#fff url(' + woocommerce_params.ajax_loader_url + ') no-repeat center',
      backgroundSize: '16px 16px',
      opacity: 0.6
    }
  });

  if (product.image.length) {
    product.image = "<img class='added-product-image' src='" + product.image.get(0).src + "' />";
  }
  base.clicked_product = product;
});

//а с этого файла все случается..
jQuery(function(a) {
  return "undefined" == typeof wc_add_to_cart_params ? !1 : void a(document).on("click", ".add_to_cart_button", function() {
    var b = a(this);
    if (b.is(".product_type_simple")) {
      if (!b.attr("data-product_id")) return !0;
      b.removeClass("added"), b.addClass("loading");
      var c = {
        action: "woocommerce_add_to_cart"
      };
      return a.each(b.data(), function(a, b) {
        c[a] = b
      }), a("body").trigger("adding_to_cart", [b, c]), a.post(wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url, c, function(c) {
        if (c) {
          var d = window.location.toString();
          return d = d.replace("add-to-cart", "added-to-cart"), c.error && c.product_url ? void(window.location = c.product_url) : "yes" === wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_redirect_after_add ? void(window.location = wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_url) : (b.removeClass("loading"), fragments = c.fragments, cart_hash = c.cart_hash, fragments && a.each(fragments, function(b) {
            a(b).addClass("updating")
          }), a(".shop_table.cart, .updating, .cart_totals").fadeTo("400", "0.6").block({
            message: null,
            overlayCSS: {
              opacity: .6
            }
          }), b.addClass("added"), wc_add_to_cart_params.is_cart || 0 !== b.parent().find(".added_to_cart").size() || b.after(' <a href="' + wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_url + '" class="added_to_cart wc-forward" title="' + wc_add_to_cart_params.i18n_view_cart + '">' + wc_add_to_cart_params.i18n_view_cart + "</a>"), fragments && a.each(fragments, function(b, c) {
            a(b).replaceWith(c)
          }), a(".widget_shopping_cart, .updating").stop(!0).css("opacity", "1").unblock(), a(".shop_table.cart").load(d + " .shop_table.cart:eq(0) > *", function() {
            a(".shop_table.cart").stop(!0).css("opacity", "1").unblock(), a("body").trigger("cart_page_refreshed")
          }), a(".cart_totals").load(d + " .cart_totals:eq(0) > *", function() {
            a(".cart_totals").stop(!0).css("opacity", "1").unblock()
          }), a("body").trigger("added_to_cart", [fragments, cart_hash, b]), void 0)
        }

      }), !1
    }
    return !0
  })
});
//заканчивая здесь
```

```html
<li id="shopping-button">
  <a class="shopping-button" href="#">
    <span class="shop-icon">
          <span class="count">1</span>
    </span>
    <b><span class="amount">руб.360000</span></b>
  </a>
  <!--/ .shopping-button-->
</li>

<!--Предположительно этот обработчик class-wc-ajax.php-->
/** * AJAX add to cart */ public static function add_to_cart() { ob_start(); $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $_POST['product_id'] ) ); $quantity = empty( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity']
); $passed_validation = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity ); $product_status = get_post_status( $product_id ); if ( $passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity ) && 'publish' ===
$product_status ) { do_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id ); if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) == 'yes' ) { wc_add_to_cart_message( $product_id ); } // Return fragments self::get_refreshed_fragments(); } else
{ // If there was an error adding to the cart, redirect to the product page to show any errors $data = array( 'error' => true, 'product_url' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink( $product_id ), $product_id ) ); wp_send_json(
$data ); } die(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <span class="amount">руб.360000</span>
> ```

Потому что скрипт, который ты не удосужился привести в вопросе, кривой.
Находишь место, где формируется эта надпись и правишь.

> он то так `<span class="amount">руб.360000</span>` то так выводит: `<span class="amount">360000&nbsp;руб.</span>`

По описанию в вопросе могу предположить, серверный код выводит верно, а джаваскриптовый - нет. Соответственно, его и править.

Comment: я его не писал и не так легко его обнаружить в недрах wordpressа. да и если его обнаружу, то что править: он то так
<span class="amount">руб.360000</span>
то так выводит:
<span class="amount">360000&nbsp;руб.</span>

Comment: @Вася, дополнил ответ.

Comment: а где его искать? в скрипте темы? в моем скрипте его нету..

Comment: по поиску выдает более 1000 страниц.

Comment: А я-то откуда должен знать где? У тебя хоть код есть.

Comment: а принудительно местами можно как-то поменять?

Comment: @Вася, при помощи css нельзя, потому что это цельный текст.

Comment: я имел ввиду jquery. обнаружил, что это ajax так балуется, т.к. снять галочку "Включить AJAX к кнопкам добавления в корзину" снимает эту проблему, но не нашел пока в каком месте он это делает

Comment: Не там ищешь...

Comment: как не там? почему? ведь снятие галки снимает проблему и все расставляет на свои места..

Comment: Это написано даже в моём ответе.

Comment: Хотя.. Возможно и там.

Comment: я уже сузил поиски нужно куска-фрагмента - не поможешь подсказать в каком именно куске срабатывает?

Comment: Не похоже. Попробуй обработчик для `.trigger("adding_to_cart", [b, c])` и `.trigger("added_to_cart", [fragments, cart_hash, b])` поискать. Скорее второй.

Comment: ок, буду искать. перенес вверх код js

Comment: я добавил предполагаемые обработчики в верхнее сообщение